# How to properly allocate and free memory from 2D array within array list within struct?

Tags: c, arrays, struct, malloc, free

I am writing a program that has a bigger struct and a smaller struct, the smaller one holding names of friends of the person in index 0 of a 2D array in Friends. I wrote the whole thing from scratch a few times and it keeps giving me either seg fault or `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)`.

Here are my structs:

Comment: Please post all related code. what does `expandBig` do? What does `expandFriends` do? Please post an [MCVE]. Please post all code in one big code block, so that it is easy to copy it.

Comment: With `add2people(People * people, char * val)`, who are the 2 people added?

Comment: There is no "2d array in Friends".

Answer (score 2):

`expandBig()` and `expandFriends()` do not assign values to the new data.

Looks like *at least* a problem is name assignment.

`friends->name[friends->size]` is not assigned a value after `expandFriends(friends)`, so `strcpy()` fails.

```
void addFriend(Friends * friends, char * val) {
  if(friends->size == friends->cap)
      expandFriends(friends);
  strcpy(friends->name[friends->size], val);
  ....
```

Consider using `strdup()`

```
  // strcpy(friends->name[friends->size], val);
  friends->name[friends->size] = strdup(val);
```

... and in `InitializeFriends()`

```
  friend->name[i] = NULL;
```

---

Code such as below is **tedious** to review.
Was the size right?  IDK, now have to trudge up to  `friend`, find its type. OK that is `Friends`.  Now look for `Friends` definition and see member `char ** name`.   OK, now with `char **` de-referenced we get `char *`.  That matches codes `sizeof(char*)`, so `sizeof(char*)` OK.

```
friend->name = realloc(friend->name, sizeof(char*) * friend->cap);
```

Save time.  Code to the size of the de-referenced pointer, not the type.  This is easier to code right, review and maintain.
Was the size right?
Yep, by construction, `sizeof *(friend->name)` is the right size.

```
// friend->name = realloc(friend->name, sizeof(char*) * friend->cap);
friend->name = realloc(friend->name, sizeof *(friend->name) * friend->cap);

// People * ret = (People*)calloc(DEFAULT_CAP, sizeof(People));
People * ret = calloc(DEFAULT_CAP, sizeof *ret);
```

Unclear why code *sometimes* casts the return from a `*alloc()` call and sometimes did not.  The cast is not needed.